# Can I add another static row for breadcrumb navigation in ssrs?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report which looks like this,

[image]

I want to add breadcrumb navigation on top of header row like this,

```
Main Table > Child Table
Table Header Rows...
Table Detail Rows...
```

All of my tables are on new pages.

**Why I want breadcrumbs above table header row ?**

Because I want it to freeze when user going to scroll down the report.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can add a static row above the header column by right clicking on the gray box next to the row and Insert Row --> Above.

You can only use the left cell though. You won't be able to merge it with the one above Name because of the grouping for the Names.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Hann, I can add a row above but then I can't merge or move cells around, which won't going to let me add breadcrumbs the way I want them to be visible

Comment: Ah - the Name grouping won't let you merge the cells. How about putting the table in another table that's group by your breadcrumb criteria.